# Show content after the first and second paragraph

Tags: content, conditional-content

The function below is used to show certain content after the first paragraph. I would like to show 'content X' after the 1st paragraph and 'content Y' after 2nd paragraph.

```
<?php
$paragraphAfter= 1; //display after the first paragraph
$content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());
$content = explode("</p>", $content);
for ($i = 0; $i <count($content); $i++ ) {
if ($i == $paragraphAfter) { ?>

<div>Insert content here</div>

<?php }
echo $content[$i] . "</p>";
} ?>
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My way to do this (**see update below**):

```
function addParagraphs($content) {
    // you can add as many as you want:
    $additions = array(
        '<p>After 1st paragraph</p>',
        '<p>After 2nd paragraph</p>'
    );

    $content = get_the_content();

    $output = ''; // define variable to avoid PHP warnings

    $parts = explode("</p>", $content);

    $count = count($parts); // call count() only once, it's faster

    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
        $output .= $parts[$i] . '</p>' . $additions[$i]; // non-existent additions does not concatenate
    }
    return $output;

}
add_filter('the_content','addParagraphs');
```

**Answer is updated according to subsequent comments**:

```
$paragraphAfter[1] = '<div>AFTER FIRST</div>'; //display after the first paragraph
$paragraphAfter[3] = '<div>AFTER THIRD</div>'; //display after the third paragraph
$paragraphAfter[5] = '<div>AFTER FIFtH</div>'; //display after the fifth paragraph

$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
$content = explode("</p>", $content);
$count = count($content);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
    if ( array_key_exists($i, $paragraphAfter) ) {
        echo $paragraphAfter[$i];
    }
    echo $content[$i] . "</p>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Max Yudin, but unfortunately not served to me. I would like to show, for example, after the 1st and the 5th paragraph, not necessarily after the 1st and 2nd.

Comment: @Michael, do you want to use it on per post basis?

Comment: Yes @Max Yudin, I want to display contents after certain posts in the loop, on home page.

Comment: @Michael, does it have to be the same content after one paragraph and the same after other(s)?  
And do you use it in `functions.php` or template?

Comment: May be the same content, @Max Yudin. I'm currently using the template.

Comment: @Michael, one more solution version added based on your code to use in template.

Comment: Great @Max Yudin. Perfect, I have no words to thank you for the help ... Thank you, lol.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );

function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {

    $ad_code = '<div>Ads code goes here</div>';

    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 2, $content );
    }

    return $content;
}

// Parent Function that makes the magic happen

function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {

        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }

        if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
        }
    }

    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I knew it's old question but this answer should help the people still looking for it.

This plugin works perfectly in any theme.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-post-ads

You can choose first / second or whatever you like to display your ads.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to make calls get_template and here I share it in case it is useful

```
<?php 
            $paragraphAfter[1] = "get_template_part( 'part-related', 'ad-first' );";
            $paragraphAfter[3] = "get_template_part( 'part-related', 'ad-third' );"; //display after the fifth paragraph
            $paragraphAfter[5] = "get_template_part( 'part-related', 'ad-fifth' );";


            $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
            $content = explode("</p>", $content);
            $count = count($content);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
                if ( array_key_exists($i, $paragraphAfter) ) {
                $string = eval($paragraphAfter[$i]); // Eval string
                    echo $string;
                }
                echo $content[$i] . "</p>";
            }
     ?>
```